# How to distiguish when to use .val() or .text() dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be able to know when to use `val()` and when to use `text()` with jQuery dynamically.

If I have a `span` and an `input` with the same class name, I need to apply `val()` on the inputs and `text()` on spans to set it's value/content.

Here is my HTML markup

```
<input class="att" name="some1" value="" type="text"><br>
<input class="att" name="some2" value="" type="text"><br>
<input class="att" name="some3" value="" type="text"><br>

<div class="att"></div><br>

<div id="test" class="att"></div><br><br>

<div id="cl">Click Me</div>
```

Here is what I tried which is not setting the value as expected

```
$(function(e){

    $('#cl').click(function(e){
     //Select any input that has the class "att" and apply the val() function
     $('.att :input').val('123');

     //Select any element that is not an input and apply the text() function
     $('.att').not(':input').text('123');

     //Search for an element with a known ID but apply `val()` if the element is input
     $('#text .att :input').val('123');

     //Search for an element with a known ID but apply `text()` if the element is not an input
     $('#text .att').not(':input').text('123');

  });

});
```

I also created a [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqxsdsyb/4/) with my code

How can I correctly apply the val() and text based on the element type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong selectors. Thats why you are not getting desired results. Use space between selectors when you need search further elements inside them, don't use them otherwise.

it should be `.att:input`
and

```
#text.att:input
```

and

```
#text.att
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gqxsdsyb/5/

Comment: Thank you. that did it. I will accept your answer when allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try the .is() function. You can do element detection with that. For example,

```
if ($(element).is("span")){/* set text */}
// or
if ($(element).is("input")){/* set val */}
```

Comment: Please check here https://jsfiddle.net/gqxsdsyb/6/ I tried to use is but it is not working